# Parameter not estimating due to singular information matrix and mutually exclusive categories in R

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, estimation, mathematical-statistics, rms

I have some data that has two categorical variables that are somewhat correlated (there is a row and a column of zeros where the levels are mutually exclusive), similar to the tabulation below.

```
                                    TREATMENT
TREATMENT_DURATION    no_treatment  treatment_1  treatment_2  treatment_3
no_treatment                a           0             0           0   
treatment_duration_1        0           b             c           d
treatment_duration_2        0           e             f           g   
treatment_duration_3        0           h             i           j   
treatment_duration_4        0           k             l           m   
treatment_duration_5        0           n             p           q
```

I'd like to create a logistic regression model using the `treatment` and `treatment_duration` variables so that the model would take the form $$\text{Y} \sim \text{treatment} + \text{treatment_duration} + \epsilon $$ where `no_treatment` is the reference level for both variables.

The model would then look like: 
$$\text{Y} \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{t1} + \beta_2 \text{t2} + \beta_3 \text{t3} + \beta_4 \text{td1} + ... + \beta_7 \text{td4} + \beta_8 \text{td5} + \epsilon$$ where "td" = "treatment duration" and "t" = "treatment."

I was hoping that by formulating the model this way, there would result in no collinearity issues with the ability to estimate the 
"no treatment" effect (estimated by $\beta_0$). When I run this model in R using both `rms::lrm` and `stats::glm`, a single parameter won't estimate (say, $\beta_8$). `rms::lrm` provides the error that there is a singular information matrix with the offending variable `td8.` `stats::glm` runs the model without error, providing `NA` for the offending variable with no entry in the covariance matrix.

My question is: why would this happen? Why is the model not able to estimate all parameters? I think I'm missing something here - probably some theory in parameter estimation and information matrices.

I've created a reproducible example in R:

````r
library(dplyr)
library(rms)
dd <- data.frame(treatment = sample(1:4, size = 20000, prob = c(.15, 0.8, 0.03, 0.02), replace = T),
                  y = sample(0:1, size = 20000, replace = T))
dd <- dd %>%
  mutate(treatment_duration = ifelse(treatment == 1, 1, sample(2:6, size = n(), prob = c(.35, 0.35, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05), replace = T))) %>% 
  mutate(treatment_duration = factor(treatment_duration, 
                                     levels = c("1","2","3","4","5","6"), 
                                     labels = c("No treatment","1","2","3","4","5"))) %>% 
  mutate(treatment = factor(treatment,
                            levels = c("1","2","3","4"), 
                            labels = c("No treatment","1","2","3")))

table(dd$treatment, dd$treatment_duration, useNA = "always", dnn = c("Treatment", "Treatment duration"))

              Treatment duration
Treatment      No treatment    1    2    3    4    5 <NA>
  No treatment         3006    0    0    0    0    0    0
  1                       0 5575 5566 3213  838  788    0
  2                       0  210  229  107   34   23    0
  3                       0  157  117   91   25   21    0
  <NA>                    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

table(dd$y, dd$treatment)

    No treatment    1    2    3
  0         1486 8004  311  203
  1         1520 7976  292  208

table(dd$y, dd$treatment_duration)

    No treatment    1    2    3    4    5
  0         1486 2987 2962 1713  440  416
  1         1520 2955 2950 1698  457  416

lrm(y ~ treatment + treatment_duration, data = dd)

singular information matrix in lrm.fit (rank= 8 ).  Offending variable(s):
treatment_duration=5 
Error in 1:ns : argument of length 0
In addition: Warning message:
In lrm(y ~ treatment + treatment_duration, data = dd) :
  Unable to fit model using “lrm.fit”

glm(y ~ treatment + treatment_duration, data = dd, family = "binomial")

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ treatment + treatment_duration, family = "binomial", 
    data = dd)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)           treatment1           treatment2           treatment3  treatment_duration1  
           0.022622            -0.021672            -0.081468             0.006154            -0.010344  
treatment_duration2  treatment_duration3  treatment_duration4  treatment_duration5  
          -0.003245            -0.008613             0.038450                   NA  

Degrees of Freedom: 19999 Total (i.e. Null);  19992 Residual
Null Deviance:      27730 
Residual Deviance: 27720    AIC: 27740
```
````

Answer (score 0):

After thinking this through some more - intuitively (not mathematically), I think this happens because of redundancy and degrees of freedom. For example, suppose we are trying to categorize an observation. We look at the "treatment_duration" variable and find that it's in none of the "treatment_duration" 1-4 categories, so it's either in the "no treatment" category or "treatment_duration_5" category. Then, we look to the "treatment" variable and find that it's in none of the treatment groups, so it must be in the "no_treatment" category. We no longer need to check if it's in the "treatment_duration_5" category because of this redundant information. So, I think this is similar to what's happening in the parameter estimation.